# responsive layout-- trying to hide element

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building a responsive image gallery page which can be viewed [here](http://tinyurl.com/8gk5ey9). Using media queries, I've successfully defined alternate layouts for the iPad-- both portrait and landscape orientations-- but I'm having a problem hiding a key element for the iPhone viewport. The problem stems from the fact that I'm using jQuery-- via the "galleriffic" image gallery plugin-- to dynamically display the #gallery div, thereby allowing for graceful degradation if one disables javascript (in which case only the thumbnails will be displayed.) I ultimately want to replicate this behavior-- i.e. only displaying the thumbnail block-- in the iphone-targeted media query, but setting both the #gallery ID and .content class to "display:none" has no effect, I'm assuming because the galleriffic script is specifying "display:block" as an inline declaraction.

Adding "!important" to "display:none" doesn't seem to help; is there any way for me to somehow override the jQuery inline declarations? I suppose one option is just to disable the script for the iPhone, but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution...

Thanks much for any guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!important` declaration goes inside the CSS property value, before the semicolon: `display: none !important;`. That should fix it :-p

Comment: oh man thanks for pointing that out! what a silly mistake. time to take a break...

Comment: np, do the same all the time :-p